# Styling the header of a webgrid in mvc

Tags: css, webgrid

I have the column below and I will like to style the header. I have not had any luck doing this. Do you have an idea?

```
gridColumns.Add(grid.Column("PastDue", header: T("PastDue"), canSort: false, format: item => item.PastDue));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to style column headers.

```
$("#myTable th:first").css({
    "background-color": "green"
});
```